# TestlinkApiException: Project and test case was not found

Tags: selenium, testlink

I have added Developer's key and test cases name in my script of Testlink automatic execution still it gives me an error as "Test Project was not found and test case was not found.

Can anyone help me for solving this issue?

```
public static String DEVKEY="80851b38d9b926cbc62c800b0742d3fc";

public static String URL="http://loacalhost/testlink/lib/api/xmlrpc/v1/xmlrpc.php";
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide PojectName, TestPlanName, TestCaseName, BuildName, Notes/Exception, Results to the test link API to update the results. Check the below code for more info.

```
TestLinkAPIClient testlinkAPIClient = new TestLinkAPIClient(DEV_KEY,
                                SERVER_URL);
         testlinkAPIClient.reportTestCaseResult(PROJECT_NAME, PLAN_NAME,
                                testCase, BUILD_NAME, exception, result);
```

Comment: I have added this all information properly still it gives me an error for TestNG Exception : Method requires 6 parameters but 0 were supplied in the @ configuration annotation